# Removing first and third zeros of a fieldname in label expression

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, python-parser

The fieldname only has three characters. I dont want to display zeros in the first and third values. example below.

010 = 1

100 = 10

01Y = 1Y

10Y = 10Y

I have figured out how to strip out zeros except for the second value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Python as the parser, and check the Advanced box. Then just replace `yourFieldName` with the name of the field you want to label.

```
def FindLabel([yourFieldName]):

    value = [yourFieldName]

    first = False
    third = False

    if value[0] == "0":
        first = True
    if value[2] == "0":
        third = True

    if first == True and third == False:
        return value[1:]

    elif first == False and third == True:
        return value[0:2]

    elif first == True and third == True:
        return value[1:2]

    else:
        return value
```

Answer (score 5):

For brevity's sake:

```
def FindLabel ([field]):
  val = [field]
  return ''.join([j for i, j in enumerate(val) if j != '0' or i == 1])
```

Step through the string and toss away all 0's unless it's in the middle position (index of 1), then join what's left.

Comment: Thank you. This worked great. I am still learning. Going to look into how that third line works.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a little more concise way of doing it. Basically convert it to a list and replace list[0] and list[2] with '' if the value is 0

```
def FindLabel([field]):
    value = [field]
    l_value = [x for x in value]    # turns string to list

    no_zero_positions = [0,2]       # where you don't want zeros
    for p in no_zero_positions:
        if l_value[p] == '0':
            l_value[p] = ''         # Replace zero with empty string

    return ''.join(l_value)        # list back to string
```

Comment: So replace value with the fieldname? I am getting errors running this exactly as it is written.

Comment: change it to `for i in no_zero_positions`

Comment: yes, I noticed that and changed it to a p instead of an i. And yes just replace !YOUR_FIELD! with your field name

Answer (score 3):

Just for good measure, here's a way to use python string methods.  This would work with strings of variable length, though I know that wasn't a consideration in this case:

```
def FindLabel(value):

    if value.endswith("0"):
        value = value[:-1]  # slice all but the last character if it's a 0
    return value.lstrip("0") # take off any leading zeros
```